# Using html 5 to inject into a jQuery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery stock ticker, it pulls out the latest stocks; Company Name, price of stock and percentage changed are shown.

Stock price can either be in GBP, USD or YEN. the current ticker does not show this.

Ideally i would like this automated but with the aging google finance api I do not think it is possible.

I have added a HTML 5 "data-currency" to define the currency for each stock manually. but I cannot get Jquery to pull it out. my attempts leave me with "undefined" spanning the column.

A similar example already exists called "data-symbol" although this is reliant on  "data-title". so replacing these to cater for the currency is not a viable option.

I am new to jquery so I know i'm likely doing something wrong.

I have attached a JS Fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer = $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t + '"]');
            var divCurrency = $('*[data-currency="' + stockInfo1.d + '"]');
            var percentStock = !isNaN(stockInfo1.c) && !isNaN(stockInfo1.l) && stockInfo1.l ? ((parseFloat(stockInfo1.c)/parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)) * 100) : undefined;
            var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
            var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;
            var stockCurency1 = stockInfo1.d;


            var stockPrice2 = "";

            stockPrice2 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.l + '</span>';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jhm7po6d/4/

How do I get HTML to print into a jquery table

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
$("#currency").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.d + "</b></div>");
```

change

```
$("#currency").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.l_cur + "</b></div>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jhm7po6d/5/

Comment: How did you know this? is this part of the google finance API or am I missing someing. It is almost perfect accept I believe if the price is in USD it does not list the currency type. Is there anyway of getting this to display to?

Comment: you can try console.log(response[0]) it will print the response data comes from google in firebug console.

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason why some of the currencies are not listed?

Answer (score 1):

Currency doesn't appear to be included in the JSON returned from Google.

```
[{
"id": "26677"
,"t" : "ASTE"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "38.17"
,"l_fix" : "38.17"
,"l_cur" : "38.17"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"4:48PM EDT"
,"lt" : "Sep 1, 4:48PM EDT"
,"lt_dts" : "2015-09-01T16:48:00Z"
,"c" : "-1.34"
,"c_fix" : "-1.34"
,"cp" : "-3.39"
,"cp_fix" : "-3.39"
,"ccol" : "chr"
,"pcls_fix" : "39.51"
}]
```

You're storing the currencies in hidden div that you can use.  You already have it in divContainer so use that.

Change

```
$("#currency").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.d + "</b></div>")
```

to

```
$("#currency").append("<div><b>" + $(divContainer).attr( 'data-currency') + "</b></div>");
```

NOTE: changing to stockInfo1.l_cur doesn't seem to show the currency.